# Unable to pull data from JSON file, ReferenceError getFile is not Defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am unable to pull JSON file data from the Uniswap_Surface_Rates.json file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMYvl.jpg)It keeps giving me Reference error : getFile is not defined.

I think I'm not entering the relative path correctly but neither google nor youtube searches have helped.

These are the absolute paths for the files

F:\Downloads\Triangular Arbitrage\RESOURCES\Uniswap2JS\main.js

F:\Downloads\Triangular Arbitrage\RESOURCES\UniSwap2\Uniswap_Surface_Rates.json

```
// GET DEPTH //////////////////
async function getDepth(amountIn, limit) {
  
    // Get JSON Surface Rates 
    console.log("Reading Surface Rate Information...")
        let fileInfo = getFile("..\UniSwap2\Uniswap_Surface_Rates.json");
        fileJsonArray = JSON.parse(fileInfo);
        fileJsonArrayLimit = fileJsonArray.slice(0, limit);
        console.log(fileJsonArrayLimit);
    
    
        return
    }

    getDepth(amountIn=1 , limit=2)
```

Comment: Where is the getFile function defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your error says:

> ReferenceError getFile is not Defined

This means the `getFile` itself is not defined. So the problem is not with the path.

Where is the `getFile` function declaration? Or where are you importing it from?

Maybe you meant to use [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback)? Or [fsPromises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options)?

But if you do have a `getFile()` declared or imported somewhere, please add it to the question, along with the rest of the code where you import the function into the file you declared `getDepth()`.

Comment: Thank you very muchfor your reply. I was just following a tutorial he must have defined it elsewhere, I will look into it.